# Subsampling very long time series in R with the goal to display it

Tags: r, timeserieschart

**Background:** I have a very long vector (think many millions of rows) that I cannot display easily, as the data is simply too large. The data is time-series - it exhibits temporal dependency.

My goal is to somehow visualize a part (or parts) of it that is representative enough (i.e. not just the first 10k rows or so)

Normally, if the data were iid and I wanted to display a part of it, I would just do resampling with replacement.

**Question** Since the data is time series, I was thinking of using "block resampling" (I don't know if this is a real term, I was thinking more of block bootstrap but without actually computing any statistics). Does anybody have a good idea (or even packages) of how I can achieve what I am looking for in a clever way?

Comment: You might want to check out `rolling_origin` from rsample package or `createTimeSlices` from caret. Same author for both packages.

Comment: Thank you, will take a look! Didn't know about it